# Return string between last comma and last bracket

Tags: regex, grafana

I am trying to transform some fields in Grafana through regex, but I am unable to get rid of the final bracket in strings formatted like:

`process_cpu_usage[redactedinformat.ion,redacted.clusterstuff,REDACTED,also,this_is_what_i_want]`

Such as it returns:

`this_is_what_i_want`

Currently this regex works but returns the final bracket, which I don't want:

```
^.*?([^\t,]*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bHTwExwC_jUWyY0h)

Comment: Does it always end with a `]`? If so maybe `([^,\t]+)\]$` would work?

Comment: @user3783243 Yes. It always ends in a `]`.

Comment: You can remove the newline in the example, and then write the pattern like this `^.*,([^\t,]*)]$` without the non greedy quantifier.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you sir - that worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

This regex finds the siring composed of anything but a comma and closing bracket enclosed with a comma (from left) and bracket followed by the end of the line (from right).

```js
const text = 'process_cpu_usage[redactedinformat.ion,redacted.clusterstuff,REDACTED,also,this_is_what_i_want]'

const regex = /\,([^\,\]]+)\]$/;

let x = regex.exec(text);

console.log(x[1]);
```